# Typescript generic constraint on class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make a very simple Local Storage utiliy method. I want to get an entry according to a key (of course) and a specified type.

Here is the code:

```
get<T>(key: string): T {
  const data = localStorage.getItem(key);
  const object = JSON.parse(data) as T;
  if (!object) {
    throw new Error(`Casting ${JSON.stringify(data)} is impossible`);
  }
  return object;
}
```

As you know, the casting `as T` is not efficient enough.
For instance, if my entry in Local Storage is <'key', 10>, Then:
`get<NoMatterTheClass>('key')` will return 10 as a number and won't throw the error.

So my question is: how can I make sure that the cast is possible?
A generic constraint ? I tried with `<T extends (new() => T)>` but it does not work

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. `as T` is a type assertion, which will throw an error if the type doesn't match. However, type check only happens in development time, not run time. Therefore, the `JSON.parse(data) as T;` won't convert `JSON.parse(data)` to `T`. It just tells the compiler that `JSON.parse(data)` is `T` as you're very sure about that when you assign `as T` to that value. So there'll be no way to do that with `TypeScript`. You can only use `Javascript` to check it.